# Ruby on Rails not working on Netbeans

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans-7

I am trying to run RoR on Netbeans 7. I installed everything as given in the documentation. I have `Ruby 1.9.2` and `Rails 3.0.9` installed on my PC.

Also I have the plugins installed with the Netbeans 7.0

But when I try to create a new project, the progress hangs on 25% and Netbeans stops responding. I have to use task Manager to close the IDE. What is wrong in the scenario? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well help on this will be limited because netbeans no longer supports Rails:
http://netbeans.org/community/news/show/1507.html

Good news though, you don't need netbeans to create a rails project. Just open up your terminal and run:

```
rails new APP_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time I have seen this happen Netbeans is happily awaiting input. When you create the project in Netbeans it executes `rails new APP` underneath and if that process asks a question, then Netbeans will hang. Check the Netbeans output window (if it's open). You can verify this by creating the rails app on the command line.  Once you do that, open the directory with Netbeans and it should recognize the project as a Rails project.